# Multi Column RDLC report, with the data flowing from Left to Right instead of Top to Bottom

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

Does anyone know how to create an RDLC subreport with multiple columns that flow from left to right instead of Top to bottom.  The report will show a list of words, say for examples colors.  I need the colors to be displayed like this :

Red             Yellow             Blue         Black
Orange          Purple

So far I've used a subreport that's set to have 4 columns and I'm wrapping the color field in a list.  This displays the colors like this though :

Red                   Purple
Yellow
Blue
Black

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Orange

Comment: Are you trying to make a table that flows L-R a certain number of columns and then wraps?

Answer (score 13):

Chris Hays (on the Reporting Services team) has a blog entry about this very thing. It may be of help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/chrishays/archive/2004/07/23/HorizontalTables.aspx

Comment: No problem. But please mark this as the answer then, so people in the future searching for this will know this question has a solution.