# RDLC Local Report (Visual Studio 2012 Report Designer) - Multiple column flow

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, rdlc

I am converting some reports that run within a Windows application to use a local SQL report, rather than a legacy custom report builder, written a fair few years ago.

The reports are not especially complex, but I have hit a question,  that I want to avoid hacking around if possible.

I need to create a two column layout that will flow, from top to bottom of left column, to top to bottom of right column, for any number of pages.

Something like

```
List
    Column One [sub report?]
      *Contents
    End Column One
    Column Two [sub report?]
      *Contents
    End Column Two
End List
```

So I would be expecting to pass a report dataset into the parent List, and have the contents flow through column one and then onto column two, and then repeat the List on the next page, until all data consumed.

Is it possible to obtain this kind of 2 column flow?

The only solution I can think of is to pre-process a dataset so that blocks of content are already organised into pages, columns and positions. But this sounds hugely rigid, especially when it comes to fitting content to a page.

so I might create

```
Data.Page = 1
Data.Column = 1
Data.Position = 1
Data.FormattedHeading = "blah"
Data.FormattedBody = "Blah..."
Data.ImageBytes = [***]

Data.Page = 1
Data.Column = 1
Data.Position = 2
Data.FormattedHeading = "blah"
Data.FormattedBody = "Blah..."
Data.ImageBytes = [***]


Data.Page = 1
Data.Column = 1
Data.Position = 3
Data.FormattedHeading = "blah"
Data.FormattedBody = "Blah..."
Data.ImageBytes = [***]

Data.Page = 1
Data.Column = 2
Data.Position = 1
Data.FormattedHeading = "blah"
Data.FormattedBody = "Blah..."
Data.ImageBytes = [***]


Data.Page = 1
Data.Column = 2
Data.Position = 2
Data.FormattedHeading = "blah"
Data.FormattedBody = "Blah..."
Data.ImageBytes = [***]
```

etc ...

And then layout in a list operating on unique Data.Page, which contains 2 sub reports for each Data.Column, which will filter on Column and contain a List that orders by Data.Position

Might be some minor details astray, but something like that is the solution that my brain is offering me.  But it makes assumptions about the size of content, and seems "hacky".

What have I missed?  Is there  a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these other Stack Overflow questions:

- [SSRS - How to build a simple multi-column report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015098/ssrs-how-to-build-a-simple-multi-column-report)
- [SSRS - How to continue data to next column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882784/ssrs-how-to-continue-data-to-next-column)
- [Multi Column RDLC report, with the data flowing from Left to Right instead of Top to Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052677/multi-column-rdlc-report-with-the-data-flowing-from-left-to-right-instead-of-to)

Comment: Thanks Scott,  I guess adding SSRS  to the question yields some good answers.

Comment: SSRS is the best term I have found for searching on this topic.